# Overriding magento search module not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, module, catalogsearch

I just created a module for overriding magento's default search;

But it not working properly. Please help me

See my code below

**app/etc/modules/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Sid_Newsearch>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
      <depends>
                <Mage_CatalogSearch />

       </depends>
    </Sid_Newsearch>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**Sid/Newsearch/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Sid_Newsearch>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Sid_Newsearch>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <newsearch>
        <class>Sid_Newsearch_Helper</class>
      </newsearch>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <newsearch>
        <class>Sid_Newsearch_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>newsearch_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </newsearch>
            <catalogsearch_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <fulltext>Sid_Newsearch_Model_CatalogSearch_Resource_Fulltext</fulltext>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch_resource>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Sid/Newsearch/Model/CatalogSearch/Resource/Fulltext.php**

```
<?php
class Sid_Newsearch_Model_CatalogSearch_Resource_Fulltext extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext
{


    public function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)
    {
            echo  '123';
            exit();
        $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        if (!$query->getIsProcessed()) {
            $searchType = $object->getSearchType($query->getStoreId());

            $preparedTerms = Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
                ->prepareTerms($queryText, $query->getMaxQueryWords());

            $bind = array();
            $like = array();
            $likeCond  = '';
            if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE
                || $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE
            ) {
                $helper = Mage::getResourceHelper('core');
                $words = Mage::helper('core/string')->splitWords($queryText, true, $query->getMaxQueryWords());
                foreach ($words as $word) {
                    $like[] = $helper->getCILike('s.data_index', $word, array('position' => 'any'));
                }
                if ($like) {
                    $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
                    //echo ;
                }
            }
            $mainTableAlias = 's';
            $fields = array(
                'query_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr($query->getId()),
                'product_id',
            );
            $select = $adapter->select()
                ->from(array($mainTableAlias => $this->getMainTable()), $fields)
                ->joinInner(array('e' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')),
                    'e.entity_id = s.product_id',
                    array())
                ->where($mainTableAlias.'.store_id = ?', (int)$query->getStoreId());

            if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                || $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE
            ) {
                $bind[':query'] = implode(' ', $preparedTerms[0]);
                $where = Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
                    ->chooseFulltext($this->getMainTable(), $mainTableAlias, $select);
            }

            if ($likeCond != '' && $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE) {
                    $where .= ($where ? ' OR ' : '') . $likeCond;
            } elseif ($likeCond != '' && $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE) {
                $select->columns(array('relevance'  => new Zend_Db_Expr(0)));
                $where = $likeCond;
            }

            if ($where != '') {
                $select->where($where);
            }

            $sql = $adapter->insertFromSelect($select,
                $this->getTable('catalogsearch/result'),
                array(),
                Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE);
            $adapter->query($sql, $bind);

            $query->setIsProcessed(1);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

Here in the function **prepareResult** i just added **exit()** but it is not working;

Please help me , Thanks in advance

Comment: try my latest edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

As i see you are trying to rewrite the model.so you have to have rewrite the model in the following way

```
<models>
    <catalogsearch>
        <rewrite>
            <resource_fulltext>Sid_Newsearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext</resource_fulltext>
        </rewrite>
    </catalogsearch>
    <newsearch>
        <class>Sid_Newsearch_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>newsearch_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </newsearch>
</models>
```

and importantly you are trying to rewrite wrong module which doesn't exists.your class should be

Your class under Sid/Newsearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php should be like

```
class Sid_Newsearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext
```

try avoiding folder called CatalogSearch under Model.

Comment: Hi @Pradeep Sanku : it still not working

Comment: show me your code.

Comment: turn it around `<catalogsearch_resource><rewrite><fulltext>Sid_New....` instead of the current

Comment: also resourceModel `newsearch_mysql4` is deprecated, try only using `newsearch_resource` and adding them accordingly.